# Type Casting arrayList/Vector without <> in Java

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

Hello I am making a solitaire game for a school project and I am using "deck" Vectors to contain instances of a Card class for it. my problem is for the course we are using a completely out of date compiler from a company no longer supporting the product and as a result many perfectly legal java statements return an error.

casting a vector to the "Card" type will not work with the <> notation however

```
    Card drawCard = new Card ();
    drawCard = (Card) deck1.get (0);
    drawCard.draw (g);
```

is accepted by the compiler. I cant use this method for changing the classes variables so I would like to do somthing like this

```
    (Card)deck1.get (a).setY (32);
```

But that does not work either. is there a way to cast a vector as an object directly without using the <> notation? Thanks a lot and im sorry if this was hard to read/confusing/vauge etc..

Comment: You need parentheses.

Comment: Pre-Java 1.5? I'm so sorry...

Comment: BTW, those are called _generics_.

Answer (score 2):

`(Card)deck1.get (a).setY (32)` means casting the result of `setY(32)` to `Card`, which is wrong.

Use parenthesis to group the casting:

```
((Card)deck1.get(a)).setY(32);
```

Also, you could ease code readability by retrieving the result of `deck1.get(a)` into a `Card` variable first:

```
Card card = (Card)deck1.get(a);
card.setY(32);
```

Comment: You have one extra pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** If you are not using *Generic* then its safe to always check for the instance using `isntanceof` operator before casting.

Sample code:

```
Object obj = deck1.get(0);
if(obj instanceof Card){
     Card card = (Card)obj;
}
```

Comment: In 99% of pre-generics cases (where it's a homogeneous collection of a known type) the `else` block of this code would just need to throw a relevant exception anyway, and `ClassCastException` is as appropriate as anything.